# How to get textbox value in views.py django

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I am trying to get the value of a textbox from views.py but its not working for some reason.

Below is my code

**base.html**

```html
<form   method="POST" role="form" >
   {% csrf_token %}
   <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="step1">
         <div class="mobile-grids">
            <div class="mobile-left text-center">
               <img src="{% static 'images/mobile.png' %}" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="mobile-right">
               <h4>Enter your mobile number</h4>
               <!-- <label>+91</label><input type="text"  name="mobile_number" class="mobile-text" value="asdfasd" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '';}" required=""> -->
               <label>+91</label><input type="text"  name="mobile_number" class="mobile-text" value="" >
            </div>
         </div>
         <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
            <li><button type="button" class="mob-btn btn btn-primary btn-info-full" data-dismiss="modal">Finish</button></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
   </div>
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    mobile_number = request.POST.get('mobile_number')
    print(mobile_number)
    return render(request,"home.html", {'mobile_number': mobile_number})
```

I am getting `None` when I try to get the value of textbox `mobile_number`.

How can I get the correct value?

Comment: if possible please add more description. When I was trying to save the edit, SO was complaining that there is more code and less description so I had to duplicate / fragment some sentences.

Comment: try to remove action attribute of form

Comment: @AlmasK89  Removed still getting *None* value.

Comment: are you enabled "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware"  middleware? If yes, you need to send csrf token. just add {% csrf_token %} to your form.

Comment: in settings.py has django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware this value. How to send csrf token?

Comment: I changed still i am getting None value.

Comment: 1. How are you sumitting the form? There's no submit-button.
2. Also, if you have csrf-enabled, and you should get a csrf-validation error with this html, as it's missing the csrf token. (You can add it by adding the line `{% csrf_token %}` after the `<form>` declaration.) But because you are not getting that error, it would seem you aren't submitting at all.
3. Please edit your post and remove all unnecessary html code.

Comment: @skoll First of all thanks for replay, I removed unnecessary html code. Please check that and help me please

Comment: @skoll thank you so much. Based on your suggestions  I modified my code.  It's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a submit-button (`<input type="submit" value="submit"/>`) from the from.

To see the value on the form after submitting it, change `value=""`on the mobile_number -row, to `value="{{ mobile_number }}"`.

Answer (score 1):

My solution
1. You have to set action in form field as your functon in view.py
    `<form class="forms-sample" name="form" action="{% url "update_size" %}" method="post">`

2. You have make button type as submit.

   `<button type="Submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">`
3. url.py

   `path('updatesize/', views.updatesize, name='update_size')`
4. View.py
   `def updatesize(request):
   if (request.method == 'POST'):
       temp = request.POST.get('size_name')
       print("==================form================",temp)
       return redirect("/collection.html")`